# Max sum held over a month

Tags: google-sheets, formulas, google-sheets-arrayformula, microsoft-excel, excel-online

I need help with a formula that needs to calculate the max sum held at one time for each month.
In this example it would be 54 for March (12+13+14+15, held on the 29/03/2021). Month is determined by "Held from".

| Sum | Held from | To |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 10 | 01/03/2021 | 10/03/2021 |
| 11 | 05/03/2021 | 15/03/2021 |
| 12 | 14/03/2021 | still holding |
| 13 | 28/03/2021 | 10/04/2021 |
| 14 | 29/03/2021 | 29/03/2021 |
| 15 | 29/03/2021 | 29/03/2021 |
| 15 | 01/04/2021 | still holding |

Comment: Welcome. Would you please summarise the research that you did for this question, and also outline what solutions you have already tried.

Comment: Sure, I currently have a sheet where I try different methods. The closer I got was creating a column with all the days in a month and doing: SUMIF when AND(Held from < DAY < To). It's ugly but closer to what I need.